# How can I style the last element of a row?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have a horizontal list:

```
<ol>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ol>
```

And styling:

```
ol {
    list-style-type: none;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: green;
    margin-right: 50px;
}
```

The problem is that the last element on a row has a `margin-right` of `50px`. Depending on device or browser width, the width of the list will vary and elements will wrap to the second line. The problem I have is that an element will wrap when it is 50px from the right, but I want it to wrap when it is 0px from the left, meaning I would like to style the last element differently.

```
li:last-row-element {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

Is something like this possible with CSS (maybe with Flexbox) ?

I know about media queries, but I don't want to have too many of them, so I was wondering if an other solution is available here!

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/11tg3zyc/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you add a wrapper in the HTML ?

If yes, then set a negative right margin to the ol to compensate the right margin in the li

```css
div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}


ol {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin-right: -50px;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: green;
    margin-right: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<ol>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ol>
</div>
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, `margin-right: -50px` brilliant :)

Answer (score 2):

> Is something like this possible with CSS (maybe with Flexbox)?

Yes, using a flexbox layout, you could set the `display` of the `ol` element to `flex`, then add [`justify-content: space-between`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content) for even spacing between the elements and [`flex-wrap: wrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap) so that the elements wrap.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/2cwtngrq/)

```css
ol {
    list-style-type: none;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

li {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<ol>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ol>
```

---

Of course, you could also remove the margin from the last element:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/bcjcbnyv/)

```
li:last-of-type {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

You could also use the [`:not()` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) to prevent the margin from being added on the element in the first place:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/yj9eqjk1/)

```
li:not(:last-of-type) {
    margin-right: 50px;
}
```

Comment: I've tried this too, but the problem here is that when you have, for example 2 elements one will show up to the left and the other on the right. In my case I want them to behave like `loat left`

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/q0cL9tkr/

Comment: getting close :) Except that the if the `last-of-type` has wrapped, the next element to wrap will have the `margin-right`

Answer (score 1):

```
li:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to not use margin-right, but margin-left like so (supports IE 7+):

```css
ol {
    list-style-type: none;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: green;
}

li+li {
    margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<ol>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ol>
```

Alternatively, you can use margin-left on all li's and reset margin-left to 0 on first-child.`li{margin-left:50px}li:first-child{margin-left:0}`  This is supported all the way back to IE 7 as well.

If you can use newer browsers (IE 9+), then you can use the following as well:

```css
ol {
    list-style-type: none;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: green;
    margin-right: 50px;
}
li:last-of-type {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Your last example is indeed getting close to what I want, except that if the `last-of-type` wraps the next element to wrap has the `margin-right

Comment: See @vals answer below.